# Horizontal align HTML header elements

Tags: css, html, web

I would appreciate some help on this one; I have 4 elements inside of a div. As of now, they are stacked on each other but I would like them to be aligned. #ninesixty is the div they are placed in. Thanks a lot (:

HTML

```
<header>
    <div id="ninesixty">    
        <h1 id="home_link">HOME</h1>
        <h1 id="projects_link">PROJECTS</h1>
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"/>
        <h1 id="services_link">SERVICES</h1>
        <h1 id="contact_link">CONTACT</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header
{
background-color:white;
text-align:center;
}

#ninesixty
{
    height:900px;
    width:960px;
    margin-top:40px;
    background-color:white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:8px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I see 5 elements in 1 div.

Comment: Add `h1 {display:inline-block;}` or `h1 {display:inline;}` or `h1 {float:left;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block;` to all h1,img tag to get them inline.

```
h1,img{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjLaw/4/)

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block` should be on the elements that you want to be inline, not on its container.  It is not an inherited property.

```
#ninesixty h1 { display: inline-block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xx9n9/

Answer (score 1):

Add class inline to all elements within the div

```
.inline
{
        display:inline-block;
}


<header>
    <div id="ninesixty">    
        <h1 id="home_link" class='inline' >HOME</h1>
        <h1 id="projects_link" class='inline' >PROJECTS</h1>
        <img id="logo" class='inline'  src="images/logo.png"/>
        <h1 class='inline'  id="services_link">SERVICES</h1>
        <h1  class='inline' id="contact_link">CONTACT</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a rule for them

```
h1 { display: block; float; left;}
```

Comment: I guess using float messes up HTML accessibility

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use H1 multiple times on a page

if you change that to  you can use a class like this

HTML

```
<header>
    <div id="ninesixty">    
        <div id="home_link">HOME</div>
        <div id="projects_link">PROJECTS</div>
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"/>
        <div id="services_link">SERVICES</div>
        <div id="contact_link">CONTACT</div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
#ninesixty div
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```